# Qt model drag & drop - Unable to save type QJsonValue

Tags: c++, qt, qdatastream, qt5.9, qmetatype

I have a [`QAbstractListModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) to display a [`QJsonArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html), with [drag & drop implementation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views):

```
class NoteListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NoteListModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~NoteListModel() override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    // Drag & Drop:
    bool canDropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    bool dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) override;
    QStringList mimeTypes() const override {
        QStringList mimes = QAbstractListModel::mimeTypes();
        mimes.prepend("application/flynote_json");
        return mimes;
    }
    QMimeData *mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const override;
    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const override;

private:
    QJsonArray noteArray;

};
```

When I call the base implementation in my [`mimeData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#mimeData) method, I have this error:

> QVariant::save: unable to save type 'QJsonValue' (type id: 45)
>   ASSERT failure in QVariant::save: "Invalid type to save"

```
QMimeData *NoteListModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
{
    QMimeData *ret = nullptr;
    if (indexes.size() == 1){
        QModelIndex mi = indexes.first();
        if (mi.isValid()){
            ret = QAbstractListModel::mimeData(indexes);
            QJsonDocument json_mime(noteArray.at(mi.row()).toObject());
            ret->setData("application/flynote_json", json_mime.toJson());
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

So no problem, like is describe in the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#save) I add these lines:

```
// In the header (outside the class)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QJsonValue)
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const QJsonValue &myObj){ /*...*/ }
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, QJsonValue &myObj){ /*...*/ }

// In the constructor
qRegisterMetaType<QJsonValue>("QJsonValue");
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QJsonValue>("QJsonValue");
```

But I have the same problem, What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: How is your `mimeTypes()` implemented?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza I have updated

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce your example, because I really couldn't explain this behavior by looking at your code. I compiled the project with Qt 5.5 and I was able to reproduce the error message:

```
QVariant::save: unable to save type 'QJsonValue' (type id: 45).
```

Interestingly, the error vanishes with Qt 5.13, as `QVariant` already includes the QJson-Types in this version.

It seems, that I found a possible workaround for this kind of `defect`, which is the following:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QJsonDocument>

QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const QJsonDocument& myObj) {
    return out;
}

QDataStream& operator >> (QDataStream & in, QJsonDocument& myObj) {
    return in;
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QJsonDocument)


int main(int argc, char** args) {
    qDebug() << qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QJsonDocument>();
    QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(QJsonDocument());
    qDebug() << var.type();
    qDebug() << var.typeName();
    QDataStream stream;
    var.load(stream);   // Workaround: Just call load at least once before any save 
    var.save(stream);
    var.save(stream);
}
```

If you call `load` at least once before all calls of `save` the error vanishes. At least for Qt 5.5.

Unfortunately, I don't have the sources of Qt 5.5 at hand to really find the reason for this odd behavior. I also don't know what makes `QJsonDocument` so special among other classes, which don't need the call to `load`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, which qt version do you use ? Because I think that in the 5.13, QJsonValue is already define in qmetatype but not in 5.9, but maybe I'm wrong. I go check

Comment: @ThibautB.: That's a good point. I'm using Qt 5.13.0 and have not considered what might happened in older versions. In this case you might need to define all this operators for all QJson-Kind Objects. There are quite plenty of them. Maybe you can try to run my example. It should be self-contained.

Comment: this is not the problem, in the 5.9 source, QJsonValue is declared [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.9/src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.h#L117), I am going to try your example

Comment: Oh, Sorry, my last comment is false, in the cpp file, when it's a QJsonValue, the switch return [false in 5.9](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.9/src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.cpp#L1347), but in [5.13](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.13/src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.cpp#L1573), the implementation is different and return false only if the pointer is not allocate, that explain why it is working in your case.

Comment: @ThibautB.: Alright! I rebuild my project with Qt 5.5 and I was able to reproduce your error. Hooray!

Comment: @ThibautB. I updated my answer. You might want to take a look at it.

Comment: I have test your code, effectively, the error vanishes when you call `load`, but when you try after the `save` to display the stream content (`qDebug() << stream;`) it's written *"QVariant(Invalid)"*